# Nested for loops in Python compared to map function

Tags: python, loops

I'm working in python and currently have the following code:

```
list = []
for a in range(100):
    for b in range(100):
        for c in range(100):
            list.append(run(a,b,c))
```

where run(a,b,c) returns an integer (for example, it could multiply the three numbers together). Is there a faster way to either loop over these numbers or use a map function?

Thanks :)

Comment: an alternative, depending on what you want to do exactly with the run function, could be to use something like numpy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at the [itertools-module](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) and particulary the [product method](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

example usage:

```
for i in itertools.product(range(0,100), repeat=3):
    #do stuff with i
    list.append(run(i[0],i[1],i[2]))
```

Note that the function call can be shortened to:

```
list.append(run(*i))
```

in the example above. see [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) for explanation of Unpacking Argument Lists.

As an example, the output from `product(range(0,2), repeat=3))` looks like this:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: +1 for clear code. Sure you can write it in one line but when you're explaining stuff this is what people wants to see.

Comment: I disagree. A line like `list.append(run(i[0],i[1],i[2]))` makes my eyes hurt a lot more than my one line solution. The short version with `run(*i)` is acceptable, though.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use imap to do this :

```
from itertools import imap
result = list(imap(run, range(100), range(100), range(100)))
```

imap yields its result... so if you want to iterate of the results don't use the list()

Comment: Hmm... when I try to import it like you said I get the error that I cannot import name imap. I'm using python 3.0, does this matter?

Comment: @Ben `map` in Python 3 behavior as `imap` in Python 2, and this code is equivalent to `[ run(a, b, c) for a, b, c in zip(range(100), range(100), range(100)) ]` instead of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product
my_list = [run(a, b, c) for a, b, c in product(xrange(100), xrange(100), xrange(100))]
```

Or:

```
from itertools import product
my_list = [run(a, b, c) for a, b, c in product(xrange(100), repeat=3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools    
li = [run(*triple) for triple in itertools.product(xrange(100), repeat=3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

an alternative, depending on what you want to do exactly:

```
my_array = numpy.tile(numpy.arange(100),(3,1)).T
def run(row):
    return numpy.prod(row, 0)
[run(row) for row in my_array]
```

Of course, it all depends on `run`, e.g. if you want to take the product, you could also operate on the whole array, which is much faster:

```
my_product = run(my_array.T)
my_product = numpy.prod(my_array, 1)
```